# Online Hosting and online SQL database

Tags: sql-server-2008, web-applications, cloud-hosting

I am busy creating a asp.net web site and using MS SQl 2008 as the Database.

I am looking for a cloud based hosting solution for both the database and the web site.

I would like to keep the costs down, until more clients are using the system.

What are your experiences and suggestions?

If I can have decent availability and the ability to create backups (I would liek to backup to other online systems maybe Amazon S3 etc)

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to understand what SQL Azure is capable of, I suggest that you view [this PDC Video by David Robinson](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/SVC27).

Answer (score 0):

Try Windows Azure (www.windowsazure.com)

I think I saw somewhere that there's a demo version knocking about until you're ready to pay for it (after the CTP sessions finished, I mean).